# Sort Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

So I am trying to sort an array of strings with an algorithm.

NOTE: For this assignment I am not allowed to use any of the built in sort functions.

```
public boolean insert(String s)
{
  boolean result = false;
  int index = 0;
  int k = 0;
  String temp = "";

  if (numUsed < values.length)
  {
    if (index == 0) 
    {
      values[index] = s;
    }    
    else 
    {
      index = 0;
      while (values[index].compareTo(s) < 0);
      k = index;
      while (k < numUsed)
      {
        values[k + 1] = values[k];
      }
      values[index] = s;
    }
    numUsed++;
    result = true;
  }
}
```

Given the input of "apples", "cats", and "bees" the output is in the same order that it was input.  No matter what I do it just never seems to sort.

Can someone help me find the problem?

Comment: There is a lot of issues with your code. Try a cleaner approach. Especially try to separate adding values from sorting values as this is two things (or do you want to add them in a sorted way?). As a sidenote: your first while loop would cause an endless loop with that ";" at the end of the line.

Comment: Take loog on sorting algo http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. I do need to enter the values in a sorted order. My code is formatted a lot better in my IDE, but  I forgot to reformat it once I had pasted it over here. I fixed the ";", now I get bees, null, null. Any Ideas how i can fix this?

Comment: Turn off tabs in your IDE. The display problem appears to have been due to an unholy mix of tabs and spaces in the code.

Comment: Please give us [a complete program](http://sscce.org/), not just one function.

Comment: This line `while (values[index].compareTo(s) < 0);` is VERY suspect. At best, it does not do anything. At worst, you run into an infinite loop. NEVER use if/for/while statement without curly brackets.

Comment: Another thing suspect : `int index = 0; [...] if (index == 0) `. Here, `index` cannot be != 0.

Answer (score 0):

Start by going back to basics. Imagine you have a large pile of index cards randomly sorted in front of you, and you need to alphabetize them. A simple but workable method is to first find all the words starting with A, and putting those in a *separate* pile (hint: how can you mimic a separate pile in your program?). Then you go though the first pile, find all the words starting with B, and putting those in the *back* of your sorted pile (another hint).

I'd recommend putting your current code aside and starting fresh. Write a loop that goes through the unsorted array, and finds the word closest to the beginning of the dictionary. Here's some psuedocode to get you started with that:

```
String leastSoFar = "ZZZZZZ";
for each String in values:
    compare the string to leastSoFar
    if the string is closer to the start of the dictionary than leastSoFar:
        leastSoFar = ???? //I'll let you fill those in
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a collection and adding elements to a collection are, often, two separate functions.  It is, of course, possible to add elements to a collection in a manner such that the elements are sorted ... but this is a very different task from simply sorting an array of elements.

If you are simply trying to implement a simple sorting algorithm, a simple (but not optimal) algorithm that is easy to code is the "delayed replacement sort".  Pseudocode fpr the algorithm to sort into ascending order is described succinctly below:

```
 Begin DELAYEDSORT
     For ITEM=1 to maximum number of items in list-1
        LOWEST=ITEM
        For N=ITEM+1 to maximum number of items in list
           Is entry at position N lower than entry at position LOWEST?
              If so, LOWEST=N
        Next N
        Is ITEM different from LOWEST
           If so, swap entry at LOWEST with entry in ITEM
     Next ITEM
  End DELAYEDSORT
```

The delayed replacement sorting algorithm is simple to understand and easy to code.  It is typically faster than the bubble sort (fewer swaps), but still has bad time complexity O(n^2) and so it is not appropriate for sorting very large datasets.

If you really want to add items to a sorted collection, then you can add the new item to the end of your collection, and resort it using the above.  If you are working with data sets larger than a few hundred or thousand elements, then efficiency will be poor.

An alternate solution that still has O(n^2) time complexity but which can be adapted to combine the adding and sorting is the "insertion sort" whose pseudocode appears below:

```
// The values in A[i] are checked in-order, starting at the second one
for i ← 1 to i ← length(A)
  {
    // at the start of the iteration, A[0..i-1] are in sorted order
    // this iteration will insert A[i] into that sorted order
    // save A[i], the value that will be inserted into the array on this iteration
    valueToInsert ← A[i]
    // now mark position i as the hole; A[i]=A[holePos] is now empty
    holePos ← i
    // keep moving the hole down until the valueToInsert is larger than 
    // what's just below the hole or the hole has reached the beginning of the array
    while holePos > 0 and valueToInsert < A[holePos - 1]
      { //value to insert doesn't belong where the hole currently is, so shift 
        A[holePos] ← A[holePos - 1] //shift the larger value up
        holePos ← holePos - 1       //move the hole position down
      }
    // hole is in the right position, so put valueToInsert into the hole
    A[holePos] ← valueToInsert
    // A[0..i] are now in sorted order
  }
```